# React Parallax wont load Image

Tags: reactjs, image, parallax, portfolio

I'm trying to replicate this Parallax effect [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_parallax.htm) and it doesn't seem to load my image. I am using the React Scroll Parallax [Here](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro) but I can't figure out why my image isn't loading.

Here is my code:

```
import water from "../ParallaxImg/water.avif";

function RecentWork() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ParallaxProvider>
          <Parallax strength={800} style={{
            backgroundImage: {water},
            //backgroundImage: "../ParallaxImg/water.avif",
            position: "relative",
            height: "20vh"
          }}>
            <div className="content" style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              position: "relative",
              height: "100vh",
              width: "100vw"
            }}>
              <span className="img-text">Text here</span>
            </div>
          </Parallax>
    ...
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. It should be in between the picture of me and the text "My Recent Work"
[image: Screenshot of what I'm seeing]

[Here](https://github.com/Shaneeyb/Portfolio-Project-3) is my Github repo of the project.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

```
import { ParallaxProvider } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
```

```
import { ParallaxBanner } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
```

```
import water from "../ParallaxImg/water.avif";
```

```
           <ParallaxProvider>
              <ParallaxBanner
                strength={800}
                layers={[{ image: water, speed: -15 }]}
              ></ParallaxBanner>
            </ParallaxProvider>
```

Parallax banner has a `layers` attribute of which you could add your images there.

Read more here: https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/examples/banners

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry that I'm seeing this late but it really helps!! I appreciate it! : )